# Install Openfire on mac

Tags: osx-yosemite, openfire

Cince morning I have been trying to install `openfire server(4.0.1 version)` on mac(yosemite - 10.10.5).

I also installed latest jre

I tried to run open fire from preference but always give error.attached in screenshot

[image: openfire server stoped]

But suddenly, it started working but after some time again openfire server stopped working and when server started working, admin console was not working.

I have two questions:

**1)** what is feasible solution for this error?

**2)** if server starts,how to connect server to database?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is about server software and therefor better suited on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Without knowing the error, it's difficult to speculate on what may have been the cause. I would note, Openfire is a server application, and you probably don't want to run it directly from your laptop/desktop unless doing development or testing.